# Compare a non-computable real number to a rational

Tags: real-analysis, computability

Suppose we have a non-computable real number $p$. Can we determine for any rational $r$ whether $r \lt p$ or $r \gt p$?

I think that if we could, than we could approximate $p$ by rationals from above and below and "compute" it with any precision.

Comment: You're right, a Turing machine cannot determine every such inequality almost by definition, and neither can ZFC (because a Turing machine could just go through every theorem in ZFC until it finds one that asserts that $r<p$ or $r>p$; this is probably the most inefficient algorithm you can possibly imagine, but it WILL halt if such a theorem exists).

Comment: If $p$ is non-computable, how can you represent it for a turing machine to compare with a rational?